# Equivalent of SoftwareBitmap class of windows 10 in windows 8.1 ?

Tags: bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I am following a windows 10 tutorial to capture a sequence of images for windows phone. they save a captured frame (Windows.Media.Capture.capturedframe) in a softwarebitmap, how do i do that in windows 8.1 ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280230.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Over a year later and no anwer.  Is it not possible?  I'm looking for the same answer so I can use some sample code that makes use of the Windows OCR api in a desktop app.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/theuxblog/2016/10/13/using-the-microsoft-ocr-library-for-winrt-from-a-desktop-app/